# RStudio asking for certificate

Tags: r, certificate, rstudio

So after reformatting my computer and transferring my data back, whenever I boot RStudio or change project sessions, I am prompted to accept a certificate.

I have actually clicked install multiple times and successfully installed the "required" certificate but this keeps on repeating again and again.

This happens 3-4 times, clicking install certificate then OK and finally RStudio boots. You can see how this gets really annoying everytime I need to reopen my session.

Specifically the certificate is named ACCVRAIZ1 with an "issuer statement" of

"Autoridad de Certificación Raíz de la ACCV (Agencia de Tecnología y Certificación Electrónica, CIF Q4601156E). CPS en http://www.accv.es"

I have no affiliation with this body nor have seen this thing before in my past experience. I also do not like the idea of accepting a random certificate for the sake of it, even more that I have to do the whole process again and again everytime I boot RStudio

I re-installed RStudio but this happens again... weird?
Also when launching Rstudio the UAC warnings indicate that the publisher is UNKNOWN and file origin: hard drive on computer which might be the reason for the lack of "trust" of the software? (just a guess)

Anyway i'd love it if somebody could explain to me why this happens and how to stop it!

Thanks

Comment: Might be more relevant at: https://community.rstudio.com/ or https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues Also, please provide system info.